# How to merge multiple directories into one?

Tags: windows, bash, merge

I downloaded a whole website from web archive. Now I have this situation:
[image: Directory Tree]

Now, if there were only 2-3 directories, I'd be fine, however there's hundreds.How can I move this into one nice tree, with automatic renaming in case the filenames match?

P.S. I am on Windows, but I have msys2 installed, so Bash commands would do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a working bash command, I would try this out :

```
cd your/peggle/download/dir/

mkdir myfiles

cp -r --backup=t */extras/* myfiles
```

The `*` is a wildcard that will match any names (but not the `/`). `--backup=t` will add an incremented numbered suffix to destination files with matching names (`challenges.php` >> `challenges.php.~1~`, `challenges.php.~2~`, `challenges.php.~3~`, etc.).

This will copy all the files from the `<subdirectory>/extras/` into the `myfiles` directory.

You can then delete the remaining folders you don't want with `rm -r [0-9]*`. It will recursively delete all files and directories inside any element that begins with a number (`[0-9]` matches a number & `*` matches anything after that number) - Be careful not to erase any other files that you want to keep that start with a number.

Sidenote : this merging won't necessarily fix the webpage when opening the files offline, as the references inside the files can point to locations either online, or not in the right spot on your machine.

Comment: OK, this is good. I definitely could not do this command prompt. However, I've compared and there are a lot of files with the same name (but different content), so I really need a renaming function to compare the files, once they're in the same solder. Thanks for the response, though. This is definitely a step forward.

Comment: Also, this does not replace files: `cp: will not overwrite just-created 'destfilename.ext' with 'sourcefilename.ext'`

Comment: Your answer plust [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Backup-options) is all I needed

Comment: @GeorgeHovhannisian Yeah I saw the backup option, but I didn't know how to use it. You should edit it into my answer and I will approve it.